# Javascript keydown listener not working after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, listener

hoping someone can help me with this. Im making a game in html5/javascript and I want the user to be able to move the map around with the arrow keys, and carry out some code when the player clicks on the canvas. I have all that working fine but for some reason sometimes when the user clicks the canvas, the keydown listener stops working unless they click outside of the canvas again. I've tried to google it and it seems to be i want to set up delegation to fix it, but im having trouble getting it to work. Here's my current code:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){keyDown(event);});

$("#game").click(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    alert(x+" "+y);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your tag is not got the event because it hasn't a focus?

Here a solution with work in my environment.
That to make a div tag is focusable pass it tabindex="0" attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function xxx() {
              var div  = document.getElementById('x');
              div.focus();
            }
            function keyd(e) {
            alert("DDDDDDDD" + e );
            }
            </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="xxx();">
          <div tabindex="0" id='x' onkeydown="keyd(event);" style="background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;">            
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not my case, but I got an idea to solve my problem. Thanks. Losing focus was the problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

I stuck your code in jsFiddle and it appears to work every time: http://jsfiddle.net/ianoxley/fb26Y/

Just wondering which browser / OS you're using? And what happens in your `keyDown` function called in your `keydown` event handler?

Comment: Ok I'm feeling stupid now. Problem seemed to be I was using alerts to debug, and when pressing enter to get rid of the alert window the DOM was some how losing focus. Deleted the alerts from my code and its working fine now.

Comment: @James: Use `console.log` for debug messages (available via Firebug or IE developer tools, built-in in Chrome and Safari (don't know about Opera)).